# XSLT1.0/XPath 1.0 Selecting nodes by date range. Is this even possible?

Tags: xslt, xpath

Lets say I have a list of nodes that contain an attribute datetime, and I want to select only the records that occur after $compare-datetime.

```
<records>
    <record @datetime="2010-01-04T16:48:15.501-05:00"/>
    <record @datetime="2010-01-03T16:48:15.501-05:00"/>
    ...etc...
</records>
```

In xquery to select items within a date range I would do

```
/records/record[xs:dateTime(@datetime) > xs:dateTime($compare-datetime)]
```

However in XSLT 1.0 I have tried alot of different approaches and alot of searching for answers, without any luck at getting this to work.

I am beginning to think that short of parsing the actual dateTime to an integer value, this is not a simple task in xslt.

I am hoping someone can give me a definite answer on that so I can at least know what I am up against.

Cheers,

Casey

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the dates will always be in the same time zone, and have fixed-width fields (constant number of digits in each field), I believe you could take [this approach](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N7218.html#d10065e58): remove punctuation, leaving the numbers, and compare the numbers.

```
<xsl:variable name="datetime-punctuation" select="'-.:T'" />
<xsl:variable name="stripped-compare-datetime"
  select="number(translate($compare-datetime, $datetime-punctuation, ''))" />
```

Then use

```
/records/record[number(translate(@datetime, $datetime-punctuation, ''))
                 > $stripped-compare-datetime)]
```

Comment: +1. Also thought about that. May be more efficient by the way.

Comment: @Flack, yeah, I meant to say this is a more quick-and-dirty method, which will work given the above constraints, and doesn't require full parsing of the datetime data. It won't give us nice things like the difference between two datetimes, but it looks like the OP doesn't need that.

Comment: I think this does exactly what I need. I wish it covered timezone, but as long as I know the limitation I can convert everything to be uniform on the server. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

May be it's not the best solution, but I have this:

XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dates.xsl"?>
<records>
    <record datetime="2010-01-04T16:48:15.501-05:00"/>
    <record datetime="2011-01-04T16:48:15.501-05:00"/>
</records>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
    extension-element-prefixes="date">
    <xsl:import href="date.difference.template.xsl"/>
    <!-- http://exslt.org/date/functions/difference/date.difference.template.xsl -->
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>        

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <result1>
                <xsl:call-template name="date:difference">
                   <xsl:with-param name="start" select="record[1]/@datetime"/>
                   <xsl:with-param name="end" select="'2010-04-04T16:48:15.501-05:00'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </result1>
            <result2>
                <xsl:call-template name="date:difference">
                   <xsl:with-param name="start" select="record[2]/@datetime"/>
                   <xsl:with-param name="end" select="'2010-04-04T16:48:15.501-05:00'"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </result2>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<records>
    <result1>P90D</result1>
    <result2>-P275D</result2>
</records>
```

Negative difference would mean that first date occurs after the second date.

Comment: +1 Good resource. This cover Zone convertion but the use of named template (for strict standar) would make **selecting nodes** a  difficult job.

Comment: I like this approach, and its completeness but like Alejandro said it makes it a bit difficult to select nodes. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: @Casey, no problem. I would pick myself if no time conversion is necessary. My proposed solution has a lot of string work, so it 99% will be significantly slower.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that XSLT 1.0 has no built-in support for dateTimes. It's possible that you may find that someone has written a library - have a look on the XSLT FAQ

See http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/rev2/dates.html#d14938e16 for what XSLT 2.0 can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I built a C# method (so this only works with .Net XSLT):

```
<msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="user">
  <![CDATA[
   public bool largerThan(DateTime dt0, DateTime dt1) {
     return dt0 > dt1;
   }
    ]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

with namespaces

```
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
xmlns:user="urn:my-scripts"
```

and usage (snippet from my xslt doc)

```
<xsl:for-each select="../b:post[user:largerThan(@created,$created)]">
```

Comment: Yes, extensions functions can always "solve" what the language (XPath 1.0) didn't cover. **But inline foreing language definitions aren't part of standard extension mechanism**. Registering an implementation into the XSLT processor context is the standar approach.

Comment: For anyone using [tag:.net]/[tag:c#], don't spend too much time trying to get EXSLT imports working with the standard .NET XSLT transformers - use [MVP.XML](http://mvpxml.codeplex.com/) right away. It has [built-in support for ESXLT](http://mvpxml.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=EXSLT.NET).