# Filter records from xml by date

Tags: vbscript

I want get records from 2014-07-15T00:00:00-05:00 date from below xml. how can i achive this using vbscript? currently i am using this but is not working.

Set colNodes=xmlDoc.selectNodes _
'("//xyz/abc[date>'2014-07-14T00:00:00-05:00']")

```
<xyz>
<abc>
<date>2014-07-14T00:00:00-05:00</date>
<text>test1</text>
</abc>
<abc>
<date>2014-07-14T00:00:00-05:00</date>
<text>test2</text>
</abc>
<abc>
<date>2014-07-15T00:00:00-05:00</date>
<text>test3</text>
</abc>
<abc>
<date>2014-07-15T00:00:00-05:00</date>
<text>test4</text>
</abc>
<abc>
<date>2014-07-15T00:00:00-05:00</date>
<text>test5</text>
</abc>
</xyz>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking a lead from [an answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4618835/3898606), I tried this and it seemed to work:

```
Option Explicit

dim xml: xml = "<xyz><abc><date>2014-07-14T00:00:00-05:00</date><text>test1</text></abc><abc><date>2014-07-14T00:00:00-05:00</date><text>test2</text></abc><abc><date>2014-07-15T00:00:00-05:00</date><text>test3</text></abc><abc><date>2014-07-15T00:00:00-05:00</date><text>test4</text></abc><abc><date>2014-07-15T00:00:00-05:00</date><text>test5</text></abc></xyz>"

'note version 6.0 of the DOM Document
dim xmldoc: set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0")
xmldoc.async = false
' error check your XML, quit 
if not xmldoc.loadXML(xml) then
    WScript.Echo xmldoc.parseError.reason
    WScript.Quit 1
end if

dim nodes: set nodes = xmldoc.selectNodes("//xyz/abc[number(translate(date, '-.:T', ''))>number(translate('2014-07-14T00:00:00-05:00', '-.:T', ''))]")

' put results into fragment because we won't have a full valid XML document
dim frag: set frag = xmldoc.createDocumentFragment()
dim node
for each node in nodes
    frag.appendChild node
next 'node
' use result
WScript.Echo frag.xml
```

The trick is realising that XPath and XSL 1.0 do not seem to support DateTime types, so to run a numeric comparison we strip any punctuation from the data values using `translate()` before converting to a number.

One issue with this is it does not take into account your timezone component so you may get incorrect results if dates differ purely by timezone, for example. This is a starting point at least.